# MAUI: compiled binding with datatypes in another project do not work

Tags: .net, xamarin, binding, maui

When I use compiled binding within the MAUI app project, everything works as expected.

If I move the viewmodels to another project and try to refer/bind them , it does not. Also in the XAML editor it shows asif he does not know that type.

I have added a reference to the viewmodel project , do I need to do something else ?

Is it supported by MAUI ?

Comment: please post the relevant code

Comment: 1) I'm curious: What is your reason for moving viewmodels to another project? 2) Have you done this previously with Xamarin Forms? Or any of the third-party MVVM add-ins for XF?

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have an additional framework in place that covers navigation and others (i.e. [Prism](https://prismlibrary.com/docs/maui/index.html) ); MAUI has simple [Data binding through the MVVM pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/xaml/fundamentals/mvvm).

I am assuming that your other project is another MAUI project here. If so maybe make sure of a couple of things:

- Follow the standard file structure having your viewmodels and views in separate folders, under the shared project head in your solution.
- Add your "imported" viewmodel within the `<ContentPage.BindingContext>` tag of the corresponding XAML page.
- Have your ViewModel inherit from INotifyPropertyChanged

If your second project is a classic Xamarin project, the same points apply, but here is a link to the [Xamarin Data Binding Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data-bindings-to-mvvm) in case you want explicit step by steps for that as well.

Comment: I refer to my viewmodels with compiled binding xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:MauiApp2.ViewModel.Game"
             x:DataType="vm:WordGuessViewModel". Also when they are in the other project the namespaces are the same. Like say I inheret from INotifyPropertyChanged. Result is that I get compile errors because he can not find my ViewModels.

Comment: Maybe if you copy pasted the file over, your solution did not "include" the file. Look in your shared project's .csproj file to see if the ViewModel file is inlcuded. If not, find it in you solution explorer and right click on it and select "Include In Project".

Comment: I forgot to add the assembly name when refering to the clr-namespace. Something like this              xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:MauiApp2.ViewModel.Game;assembly=MauiApp2.ViewModel"

Comment: *"Also when they are in the other project the namespaces are the same."* - I doubt that is sufficient. AFAIK, The binding mechanism won't know to look in the other assembly.